# Mapbox-gl flickers when resizing the container <div>

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am working on a functionality where we can increase/decrease the Mapbox-gl container (), the resizing is done by dragging any corner of the Mapbox container. It is like increasing/decreasing a square/rectangular box. but it is flickering while increasing/decreasing the size. I am using mapbox gl js latest version v2.6.1

BUT, flickering is not happening with old Mapbox API (version v3.3.1)

Can you suggest ways to smooth experience with mapbox gl js

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I think I'm having a similar issue when a sidebar makes the map container smaller/bigger

Comment: Same here, haven't found anything.

Comment: I had problems with flickering on resize when using the `.resize()` on the map in a `ResizeObserver` while resizing the container. Then I noticed that the map was resizing smoothly when resizing the browser window instead, so I ended up dispatching a browser resize event (`window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`) instead of using the `.resize()` function, and that made it perfectly smooth. This fix (or hack) might have other implications depending on your app though, if you have other things listening on browser window resize.

Comment: When using `map.resize()`, wrapping it in a `setTimeout(() => map.resize(), 0)` seems to fix flickering